# How to instantiate VLC GUI and read from file descriptor in C?

Tags: c, ubuntu, vlc

I have a UDP server-client written in C, where client opens a file descriptor to a new/existing .mp4 file and write to it. It works very well. Here is the snippet.

```
    if (clientState->doSaveToDisk)
    {
        if (chunkNumber == 0)
        {
            // Start: make sure we're starting with an empty file.
            clientState->fileBeingTransferred = open(fileName, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0777);
        }

        ssize_t numBytesWritten = write(clientState->fileBeingTransferred, buffer, buffer_Remaining(payload));
}
if (isComplete) {
        printf("File '%s' has been fully transferred.\n", fileName);

        if (clientState->doSaveToDisk)
        {
            close(clientState->fileBeingTransferred);
        }
    }
```

Now I do not want to write it to a file, rather I want to display it in VLC.
My question is how to instantiate VLC gui when I receive first packet and then display it till the end.
Only want C and Ubuntu.
Any example would be appreciated.